# Transformer excitation current vs voltage relation

Tags: transformer

I do not understand why if I increase the voltage of a single phase transformer the excitation current is increasing.

Is it because of the rated voltage? As we know, when the primary voltage reaches its rated voltage the iron core (laminations) begins to saturate, and the exciting current increases rapidly.

[image]

Comment: I see no problem here.

Comment: Just want to know why the Excitation current is increasing linearly ? is it because of the core loss?

Comment: I think what you ask, is fundamental (like E=mc^2). The excitation current increases linearly when voltage increases. The "Why" can be found in a wikipedia page about the subject I guess.

Comment: E=mc^2 is only valid for objects which have negligible deBroglie wavelength

Comment: See Fig 10 of [this paper](https://cms-cdn.selinc.com/assets/Literature/Publications/Technical%20Papers/6811_BeyondKneePoint_AH_20200501_Web.pdf?v=20200504-195517).